# UISearchBar search not clearing old cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to implement a `UISearchBar` in a custom `UITableViewController` and done programmatically (not using IB). I got the search function to work and return the correct fields, but it is displaying the searched cells over the full list cells:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the new searched field is scrollable and selectable. Its just not removing the old cells.

here is my .h file:

```
@interface TestTableViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *boundaries;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "TestTableViewController.h"

#import "Boundary.h"

@interface TestTableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchDisplayController *searchController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *filteredBoundaries;

@end

@implementation TestTableViewController

-(instancetype) initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];

    if (self) {
        self.filteredBoundaries = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:TRUE selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    self.boundaries = [self.boundaries sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    searchBar.placeholder = @"Search Fields";
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = TRUE;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

    self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;    
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Setup Filter Data Source

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope {
    [self.filteredBoundaries removeAllObjects];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    self.filteredBoundaries = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.boundaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return self.filteredBoundaries.count;
    }
    else {
        return self.boundaries.count;
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        Boundary *boundary = [self.filteredBoundaries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = boundary.name;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }
    else {
        Boundary *boundary = [self.boundaries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = boundary.name;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
    }

    return cell;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController Delegates

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:self.searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]];

    return TRUE;
}

@end
```

And how I call the table view:

```
    TestTableViewController *tableViewController = [[TestTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableViewController.boundaries = [group.boundaries allObjects];
    tableViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = POPOVER_SIZE;

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];
    navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

    self.myPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
    self.myPopoverController.delegate = self;

    [self.myPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:button.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Your code as-is works fine for me. There is no overlap between the search results and initial set of cells. Note that you can specify a different data source and delegate for the searchController. If you use the same as the original, then you do need to check the tableView the same controller object serves as a data source for two different table views.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `UISearchDisplayController` is using another `UITableView` rather than the view controller's own. You can verify that by logging `tableView` in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

You can use a `UISearchBar` without a `UISearchDisplayController`, to have more control over search and display logic.

Also, if your app doesn't support any version prior to iOS 8, consider using [UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchController/searchResultsController). I haven't tried it but it seems to give you more control. Check a [sample](https://github.com/dempseyatgithub/Sample-UISearchController) `UISearchDisplayController`has been deprecated in iOS 8.

Comment: You are right. When a search is conducted, the `tableView` returned in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is different then the `self.tableView`. Is that how its suppose to work? If so, using a `UISearchDisplayController` makes it more difficult to use. I need to clear out `self.tableView` and only show the `UISearchDisplayController`'s `tableView`. Sounds like it would be easier to use the `UISearchBar` delegate methods and reload the self.tableView myself.

Comment: Yeah. The table view managed by ```UISearchdisplayController``` is a subclass of ```UITableView.``` I have already used ```UISearchBar``` directly. The delegate methods are clear enough.

Comment: Ok, so then what is the solution? I need to support iOS 6+, so `UISearchController` is unworkable. Clearly `UISearchDisplayController` should work correctly some how. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use a ```UISearchBar```directly. Make the view controller conform to ```UISearchBarDelegate``` and you'll have to implement a couple of its methods.

Comment: I got the basic behavior to work with just using the `UISearchBar`, but I like some of the features the `UISearchDisplayContoller` offered such as the darkening of the table view and the ability to use scope.

Comment: You can control the color by changing the cells' ```backgroundColor```. I don't know about the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 41.0)];
    [self.view addSubview:searchBar];
    searchBar.delegate=self;

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (isSearching) {
        return [filteredContentList count];
    }
    else {
        return [titlearray count];
    }
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if (isSearching)
    {
        cell.nameLabel.text = [filteredContentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image =[filteredImgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.nameLabel.text = [titlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
- (void)searchTableList {
    NSString *searchString = searchBar.text;

    for (int i=0; i<titlearray.count; i++) {
        NSString *tempStr=[titlearray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSComparisonResult result = [tempStr compare:searchString options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchString length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            [filteredContentList addObject:tempStr];
            [filteredImgArray addObject:[imagearray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }

}

#pragma mark - Search Implementation

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    isSearching = YES;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"Text change - %d",isSearching);

    //Remove all objects first.
    [filteredContentList removeAllObjects];
    [filteredImgArray removeAllObjects];

    if([searchText length] != 0) {
        isSearching = YES;
        [self searchTableList];
        //tblContentList.hidden=NO;
    }
    else {
        isSearching = NO;
       // tblContentList.hidden=YES;
    }
    [tblContentList reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Cancel clicked");
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Search Clicked");
    [self searchTableList];
}
```

I hope it's help for you

Comment: Something similar to that does work. I do have the search bar working w/out the `UISearchDisplayController`, but I would like to be able to use the search controller for its scope function.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement correct datasource.

Create new array of items for filtered data for first.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger count = ([filteredItems count] > 0) ? [filteredItems count] : [self.allItems count];

    return count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"id"];

    MyCustomItem *item = ([filteredItems count] > 0) ? filteredItems[indexPath.row] : self.allItems[indexPath.row];

    [self configureCell:cell forItem:item];

    return cell;
}
```

Configure searching:

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{

    NSString *searchText = searchController.searchBar.text;

    if ([searchText length] == 0)
    {
        [filteredItems removeAllObjects];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        return;
    }

    NSMutableArray *searchResults = [self.allItems mutableCopy];

    // SKIP ALL BODY OF SEARCHING

    filteredPeoples = searchResults;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Will work pretty.

Comment: I do have a different datasource for the filtered content,`self.filteredBoundaries` which is created in the `initWithStyle:` method. When the `UISearchDisplayController` delegate `shouldReloadTableForSearchString` is called, I call my filter method, remove all objects in the `self.filteredBoundaries` and us a `NSPredicate` to get the new list (which works) and the delegate returns true which in turn, reloads the data.

Answer (score 0):

IOS 8 delegate has been deprecated not sure if that's the problem.
The method

here's [a link]https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchDisplayDelegate/searchDisplayControS 8 delegate has been deprecated not sure if that's the problem.
The method

try this property instead

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id< UISearchResultsUpdating > searchResultsUpdater
```

another better link [a link]https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Listings/TableSearch_obj_c_TableSearch_APLResultsTableController_m.html